# Is it natural to say "3 oranges and 4 apples are the same weight"?

Tags: grammaticality, comparisons

When two groups of items have different masses, we can easily say
"3 oranges are lighter than 4 apples."
"3 oranges are heavier than 4 apples."

How about when they have the same mass? Can we say
"3 oranges and 4 apples are the same weight."

Comment: Proofreading is off topic per the [help].

Comment: @MετάEd This is not proofreading - it's asking the meaning of a particular sentence construction.

Comment: There is nothing in the question about meaning.

Answer (score 1):

The natural parallel construction would be "3 oranges are the same weight as 4 apples."  It would be slightly more common to say "3 oranges weigh the same as 4 apples."